# Conversion of string to float rounded to one decimal

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

I want 20 to be converted to 20.0  here and type to float, but can't seem to get that value and type. It's still taking 20 as str and not float. Does anyone know a way to do it ?

Comment: 1) Actual error: You didn't call `isnumeric` (you forgot the parens). 2) Never compare to `True`, a simple `if str_.isnumeric():` is idiomatic. 3) Look before you leap (LBYL) is a bad idea for parsing; testing `isnumeric` rejects stuff like `'-1'` and `'1.2'`. Just try to convert with the `float` constructor and catch the `ValueError` if it fails (EAFP pattern). 4) Include the actual code, inputs and outputs as text, not images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems easy but it can throw some errors if not handled

```py
def check_is_num(string):
    if type(string) == str:
        try:
            ret = round(float(string), 1)
        except ValueError:
            ret = string
    else:
        ret = round(float(string), 1)
    return ret

print(check_is_num("10.56"))  # Prints: 10.6
print(check_is_num("hello"))  # Prints: "could not convert string to float: 'hello'"
print(check_is_num(True))     # Prints: 1.0
print(check_is_num(False))    # Prints: 0.0
print(check_is_num(100.56))   # Prints: 100.6
print(check_is_num(100))      # Prints: 100.0
```

That should probably work for you :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. 1)All values that are taken as input are strings. 2) When I use this function on a column, it somehow doesn't work. It works it I pass individual values like you did. 3) I want the string(if it is not anumber) to be orinted as it is, without the could not convert message. Is that possible ?

Comment: Hi @SreshthaSinhaRoy. Can you provide some more info on where you use this function? Is a column a list ( `[]` )? To print the string as it is you just need to change the `ret` variable to the string and not the error. I'll alter the code.